# (litecoin) High hashrate but low amount of submitted shares in solo

Tags: litecoin, hashpower, solo-mining

I'm playing around with litecoin mining and have been mining at a pool but decided to mine solo using [cgminer](https://github.com/ckolivas/cgminer/).

When I mine at pools the amount of shares submitted to the pool sinks dramatically when I crank up the intensity (180 khash/s at intensity 11 compared to 20 khash/s at intensity 15). This is the same no matter which pool I'm on.

According to cgminer the khash/s go up as would be expected when intensity is upped.

For solo I really want to know if just the *submitted* amount of shares goes down for some reason or if a higher intensity really somehow ups the khash/s but lowers the submitted shares. cgminer's output is not easily checked for this.

Answer (score 2):

The system of shares on a pool is set by the pool owner. It is not exactly the same as mining litecoin solo, and in fact some pools will have much smaller shares (pool-x.eu) set up to encourage you to continue mining, even though you are not actually mining more litecoin. Other pools have larger shares which take longer to mine (ltc.kattare.com), but are actually less work for the server so (theoretically) you should get a bit more from the longer ones.  While solo mining you are A) getting all the shares yourself with no "pool power" and B)getting the normal share size for litecoin. Hope this helps, 5mil